# UserControl CollectionViewSource not working

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a user-control containing this XAML

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="QA.JobListControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="using:QA" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

   <UserControl.Resources>
      <CollectionViewSource x:Name="itemsSource" IsSourceGrouped="True" />
   </UserControl.Resources>

   <ListView x:Name="JobListView" Margin="-10,-10,0,0" Padding="120,0,0,60" IsSwipeEnabled="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=itemsSource}" SelectionChanged="JobListView_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
      <ListView.GroupStyle>
         <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                     <TextBlock Text='{Binding Status}' Margin="10" />
                  </Border>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
         </GroupStyle>
      </ListView.GroupStyle>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
               <TextBlock Text='{Binding TaskName}' />
               <TextBlock Text='{Binding DueDate}' />
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

And to set the content I am using this C#-code

```
itemsSource.Source = Tasks.OrderBy(Tsk => Tsk.DueDate).GroupBy(Tsk => Tsk.Status);
```

It is showing some of the elements (but they are shown as empty elements), and not all are shown 
What could be wrong?

If I am using this C#-code it is working (but it is not grouped)

```
JobListView.ItemsSource = Tasks.OrderBy(Tsk => Tsk.DueDate);
```

**UPDATE**

After adding the `StaticResource` like below, it now shows multiple groups without items

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsSource}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think you are misunderstanding the basics behind the GroupBy method. GroupBy, as opposed to most other Linq extensions, will not return a simple list of objects, instead it will return a list of IGrouping. IGrouping interface exposes a Key property which will hold the value of the grouping discriminator you passed in the GroupBy lambda.

Therefore, to get the list to display the group name, you have to bind the group header template to Key instead of Status.

```
<TextBlock Text='{Binding Key}' Margin="10" />
```

Also if reference your CollectionViewSource as a resource, you need to define a resource key to reference it later in your XAML as a StaticResource.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="itemsSource" x:Key="groupedTasks" IsSourceGrouped="True" />
```

And in the list view.

```
<ListView x:Name="JobListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedTasks}}">
```

This way I got your example to work as expected.

As an additional read I dearly recommend you to read [this article](http://dotnetspeak.com/index.php/2012/07/working-with-gridview-control-in-winrt-app/) by Sergei Barskiy which demonstrates how to use grouping in XAML lists and also provides a GroupedData class that in my opinion is much better than the default IGrouping object to expose your data and consume it in the UI.

Comment: Why can't I just reference to its name?

Comment: Yes you could. It is just that there is different schools for referencing objects within XAML. What is important is to understand what it exactly means and what it implies in terms of maintainability. The good thing about resource keys is that it makes your resources globally available throughout the underlying controls regardless of the element's DataContext. Using resource key is a better practice to maintain your views and actually I don't see any valid reason to use element name over resource key if your element is a resource.

Comment: Yes, but I am thinking of why do I have to set `x:Key`

Comment: Always give a Key to your resources.